# Android переопределение color из Resource

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

Есть несколько цветов в colors.xml. По нажатию кнопки нужно переопределить все их цвета. Если получать их ссылки как `val color =  R.color.anycolor` , то как переопределить их цвет в коде. Или есть другой способ переопределить цвет, который находится в Resource ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ресурсы статичны и после компиляции их менять не получится. Либо пишите свои врапперы (пример: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178187/7519767)), либо храните где-то в статическом классе (вашей замене ресурсов). Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос

> есть способ переопределить цвет, который находится в Resource?

— Нет.

Вы можете [поменять тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android) приложения, любым способом сделать враппер над ресурсами (ссылка на пример выше) — в общем, реализовать нужный функционал программно, не трогая сами ресурсы. Другого пути нет.

Comment: Пример , который вы указали устарел.

Comment: @Vlad на ваш вопрос я в любом случае ответил. Уж утрудите себя и найдите релевантный пример в гугле самостоятельно. Не думаю, что это составит большого труда.